# Existe un cron en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Quisiera saber si laravel tiene una librería para realizar la ejecución de tareas (en mi caso envío de correos electrónicos) cada N cantidad de tiempo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí existe, se conoce como **[Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling)**, tan solo hay que agregar la línea de comando del cron como se haría normalmente:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

En cuanto a como agendar las tareas, se puede hacer en el Kernel de la consola, en el método schedule:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            DB::table('recent_users')->delete();
        })->daily();
    }
}
```

O se pueden agendar comandos también:

```
$schedule->command('emails:send --force')->daily();
```

Entre otras opciones para lanzar los comandos y las frecuencias de estos, las cuales puedes ver en la documentación.